# Check to see if there a wordpress user account and create one if not outside of wordpress

Tags: login, account, wp-create-user

Please note that this was posted on wp-hackers mailing list.

Hi guys,

Just wondering, does anyone know how I can go about checking to see if
there a wordpress account and create one if there isn't?

Script that I got: https://gist.github.com/Danielx64/7519092

There a marker in the file that has "// Somewhere here I want to put a
check to see if there a wp account" What I want to happen there is
that a check get done to see if there is a wordpress account and if
there not, create one.

Does anyone know if it can be done?

PS, I don't need to worry about logging into wordpress as that will
get taken care of by a different script. Also anyone who can help me
out will also get credit in the source code and readme :)

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

How are you searching for this user? Either way, this it the function you want to use, as it can look via ID, `user_nicename`, email and login.

e.g.:

```
$userEmail = $_GET['useremail'];
$field = 'email';
$user = get_user_by( $field, $userEmail );

if(!$user) {
    $newUserArgs = array(
        'user_login' => $_GET['userlogin'],
        'user_pass' => $_GET['hashedpass'],
        'user_email' => $_GET['useremail']
    );
    $user = wp_insert_user( $newUserArgs );
}
```

`$user` now has user in it. Either it found an existing one, or created one. As you can see I've assumed you are passing in userlogin, hashedpass and useremail from a form or such.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you said that you are looking to do this outside of wordpress, adding the following will allow you to access the wordpress functions; `require('/var/www/path/to/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php'); 
global $wpdb;`

Comment: I managed to get what I'm after going, someone on wp-hackers given me a clean way of dealing with it. Code on github: https://gist.github.com/Danielx64/7519092 from 46 to 60

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the update. Maybe give us a link here so we can all see?

Comment: Sure you can read up on it here, http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2013-November/047347.html that has the direct answer that I'm after. Please note that I did need to edit the script but it a very good starting point :)